# Multi-inheritance with interfaces type casting on pointers for using with std::list

Tags: c++, class, oop, casting, multiple-inheritance

I come from Java (OOP) background. I made a simple class to illustrate my problem:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// classes
class InterfaceA
{
public:
    virtual std::string functionA();
};

class InterfaceB
{
public:
    virtual std::string functionB();
};

class DerivedAB : public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB
{
public:
    std::string functionA()
    {
        return "I'm a A object";
    }

    std::string functionB()
    {
        return "I'm a B object";
    }
};

// functions
void doStuffOnListOfA(std::list<InterfaceA*> aElements)
{
    std::cout << "Print list of A" << std::endl;
    for (InterfaceA* const& a : aElements)
    {
        std::cout << a->functionA() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<DerivedAB*> derivedABs;   
    doStuffOnListOfA(derivedABs);
    return 0;
}
```

I have two simple virtual classes `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` and a class `DerivedAB` that multi-inherits the two first virtual classes.

Furthermore, I then create a list of pointers of `DerivedAB` (`std::list<DerivedAB *>`) and wish to use this list with a function designed to work on a list of  `InterfaceA`-derived objects. But I get an error:

```sh
(base)  ❮ onyr ★  kenzae❯ ❮ multi_inheritance_type_convertion❯❯ make
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:54:32: error: could not convert ‘derivedABs’ from ‘std::__cxx11::list<DerivedAB*>’ to ‘std::__cxx11::list<InterfaceA*>’
     doStuffOnListOfA(derivedABs);
```

I have obviously a type casting error. I have read many articles on Stack Overflow about the different casting in C++ as well as on Multi-Inheritance, but my brain refuses to give me the answer.

---

**Edits:**

I said an erroneous statement:

> "However I'm pretty sure such a code would work in Java..."

Apparently I'm missing an important concept about type inheritance...

Comment: "*However I'm pretty sure such a code would work in Java...*" - no, it would not, becasue [collections of derived types are not derived from collections of base types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/7151494). This link explains the problem in Java which is pretty much the same in C++. I'd advise using `template`s.

Comment: F.A.Q.: [Is a parking-lot-of-Car a kind-of parking-lot-of-Vehicle?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#parkinglot-of-car-vs-vehicle)

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I did'nt know that, I will read this thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is far different from Java!

---

> I have obviously a type casting error.

You are right about this (aka. type mismatch)! The `std::list` is a standard template container which gives you a concrete type, when you instantiate with a template argument.
That means, the `std::list<InterfaceA*>` is different from `std::list<DerivedAB *>`.

This is exactly the compiler tells you:

```
error: could not convert 
from ‘std::__cxx11::list<DerivedAB*>’     ----> i.e. std::list<DerivedAB*>
to    ‘std::__cxx11::list<InterfaceA*>’   ----> i.e  std::list<InterfaceA*>
     doStuffOnListOfA(derivedABs);        ----> at the function call
```

You can not implicitly(i.e. compiler will not) convert to one another.

You need to cast each element of the `derivedABs` to base pointers or (in your case) make the `doStuffOnListOfA` as template function:

```
template<typename T>
void doStuffOnListOfA(std::list<T*> aElements)
{
    std::cout << "Print list of A" << std::endl;
    for (InterfaceA* a : aElements)
    {
        std::cout << a->functionA() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

To make sure that, one use the above only for `std::list<derived from InterfaceA and B>`, you may can (optionally) [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) the template function:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_base_of

template<typename T>
constexpr bool isBaseOfInterfaces = std::is_base_of_v<InterfaceA, T> && std::is_base_of_v<InterfaceB, T>;

template<typename T>
auto doStuffOnListOfA(std::list<T*> aElements) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<isBaseOfInterfaces<T>, void>
{
    // ... code
};
```

---

That being said,

- You need to look into the smart pointers (such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) rather than using raw pointers (manual memory management), by which you can handle the memory management smartly.
- You might want to add the `virtual` destructor in your base classes for a defined behavior. See here for more: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Here is **([the complete demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/efe3PzrGx))**

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you once more. I understand surprisingly quite well your high quality answer. Still, could you explain/give resources on the notation `auto stuff() -> std::stuff`. What is that `auto` since there is return ?

Comment: @Onyr The syntax is called **[trailing return types](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/trailing-return-types-everywhere/)**, and the `std::stuff` is one of mayn ways of doing **[SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)** and the `isBaseOfInterfaces` is a **[Variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template)**. Hope that helps!